# How to list only attribute names of a table in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, metadata

I know I can use \d  to list the schema.
However, I need to make a front end application just to display attribute names of a table. How can I get the only attribute names out in PostgreSQL?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You need to query appropriate tables under `pg_catalog` or `information_schema` schemas.
Run `psql -E ...` and then psql displays meta-data queries used in internal commands like `\d, \dt, \dv, ...`

`information_schema` is same as `pg_catalog` but more portalbe (it is defined in SQL standard). If your app uses postgres only then I would use pg_catalog instead of `information_schema`

For example, this query shows columns for `attribute`

```
SELECT a.attname,
  pg_catalog.format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
  (SELECT substring(pg_catalog.pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid) for 128)
   FROM pg_catalog.pg_attrdef d
   WHERE d.adrelid = a.attrelid AND d.adnum = a.attnum AND a.atthasdef),
  a.attnotnull, a.attnum
FROM pg_catalog.pg_attribute a
WHERE a.attrelid = 'attribute'::regclass AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
ORDER BY a.attnum
```

UPDATE:
You can use simple query like this:

```
SELECT attname 
FROM pg_catalog.pg_attribute 
WHERE attrelid = 'attribute'::regclass AND attnum > 0 AND NOT attisdropped
```

or use equivalent query:

```
SELECT column_name 
FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE table_name = 'attribute' 
ORDER BY ordinal_position
```

If you have same table with the same name in multiple schemas you need to user schema name as well and query get slightly more complex.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. However, I still don't quite understand. The query you posted shows error near 'attribute'. I tried "select attname from pg_catalog.pg_attribute;" However, it shows more than what I need.

Comment: Sorry, `attribute` is my example table name :). What's the error message? This is from Postgres 8.4 -- maybe some copy & paste formatting issue. If you have table called 'my_table' then use `... WHERE a.attrelid = 'my_table'::regclass AND ...`